# Rational functions satisfying functional equation in Weil's conjecture

Tags: number-theory

Weil's conjecture states that zeta functions of curves (or higher dimensional things) are rational which has a special form and satisfies functional equations. There are some known examples which are relatively easy to compute, such as projective space, Grassmannians and elliptic curves. My questions are following :

1. For any rational functions which satisfy the properties in the Weil conjecture can we find a corresponding curves or higher dimensional varieties? It seems very hard for me. If it is, are there any known results for some special cases?
2. If we can, does zeta function give one-to-one correspondence between those two things?

Comment: The simplest case is to find an (elliptic ?) projective curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$ whose zeta function is $\frac{1-t X+q X^2}{(1-X)(1-q X)},t \in \mathbb{Z},|t| \le 2 \sqrt{q}$

Comment: @reuns Is it possible to find such curve?

Comment: And the genus should be indicated by the coefficients of $\zeta_C(X)$ and the Riemann-Roch theorem.

Comment: Your question has been addressed already on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70605/from-zeta-functions-to-curves.

Comment: @KCd Thank you very much!